# Detect scrollHeight change with MutationObserver?

Tags: mutation-observers

How can I detect when `scrollHeight` changes on a DOM element using `MutationObserver`? It's not an attribute and it isn't data either.

Background: I need to detect when a scrollbar appears on my content element, the `overflow-y` of which is set to auto. I figured that the instant the scrollbar appears the value of `scrollHeight` jumps from 0 to, say, 500, so the idea was to set up a `MutationObserver` to detect a change in this property.

What I've got so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="body" #body>
```

**CSS**

```
.body {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**TypeScript**

```
export class MyWatchedContent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
   @ViewChild('body', { read: ElementRef })
   private body: ElementRef;

   private observer: MutationObserver;

   public ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.observer = new MutationObserver(this.observerChanges);
       this.observer.observe(this.body.nativeElement, {
           attributes: true,
       });
   }

   public ngOnDestroy() {
       this.observer.disconnect();
   }

   private observerChanges(records: MutationRecord[], observer: MutationObserver) {
       console.log('##### MUTATION');
       records.forEach((_record) => {
           console.log(_record);
       });
   }
}
```

If I, for example, change the background color in the developer window I can see the observer firing

> MUTATION
>
> my-content-watcher.component.ts?d0f4:233 MutationRecord {type: "attributes", target: div.body, addedNodes: NodeList(0), removedNodes: NodeList(0), previousSibling: null…}

If, however, I change the window size to make the scrollbar appear there's no mutation detected. Is this doable with `MutationObserver` at all and if so, how?

Comment: MutationObserver won't detect it. Try ResizeObserver or simply check periodically.

Comment: @wOxxOm even ResizeObserver not detecting changes in scrollHeight.

Comment: Hmm, IntersectionObserver may help then.

Comment: ResizeObserver might not detect scrollHeight, but it will detect content height. It should be fine to use if you're watching the content itself that will grow.

Answer (score 27):

Here's the answer, for anyone still looking for the solution:

As of today, **it's not possible to directly monitor scrollHeight changes of an element**.

- The **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** detects changes in the DOM tree, which could indicate a scrollHeight change, but that's a wild guess.
- The **[ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)** detects changes in the outer height of an element, but not the scrollHeight (i.e. "inner" height).
- There is no <strike>ScrollHeight-Observer</strike> (yet).

BUT the solution is very close:

**The Solution**

> *The ResizeObserver detects changes in the outer height of an element...*

There's no point in observing the scroll-container because its outer height does not change. The element that changes their out height is any CHILD node of the container!

Once the height of a child node changes, it means, that the scrollHeight of the parent container changed.

**Vanilla JS version**

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.scrollable-container');

const observer = new ResizeObserver(function() {
    console.log('New scrollHeight', container.scrollHeight);
});

// This is the critical part: We observe the size of all children!
for (const child of container.children) {
    observer.observe(child);
})
```

**jQuery version**

```js
const container = $('.scrollable-container');

const observer = new ResizeObserver(function() {
    console.log('New scrollHeight', container[0].scrollHeight);
});

container.children().each(function(index, child) {
    observer.observe(child);
});
```

**Further steps**

When children are added dynamically, you could add a MutationObserver to add new children to the ResizeObserver once they were added.

Comment: Element might have dynamic content, meaning children added/removed on-the-fly. Better to use `ResizeObserver` in combination with `MutationObserver` to cover all cases of both inner content change and container actual re-size

Comment: it's ridiculous that we don't have a native way of checking this in 2023.

Comment: This works for me even when no children sizes change and children are just  added/removed. However, it only works because when an overflow happens, a scrollbar appears, reducing the width of the children. And this is just in my case; it's possible this doesn't happen for you, depending on your styles. If for example you had a permanent scrollbar with `overflow: scroll`, this doesn't work. Just be aware of this edge case. A true answer would unfortunately have to be a comprehensive solution with a combination of resize and mutation observers.

Comment: You could possibly: set container `position: relative`, add a dummy child div with `position: absolute; inset: 0`, then use a resize observer on that. Just speculating here.

Comment: It's better to have only one child wrapper, then there is no need for MutationObserver to observe newly added elements

Answer (score 4):

You can emulate this behavior by adding an internal wrapping element on the `contenteditable` element (eg a `span`) and then add the `ResizeObserver` listener on the internal element. The internal `span` has to be `display:block` otherwise it wont trigger the `ResizeObserver`.

### HTML

```html
<div contenteditable id="input"><span id="content">Some content</span></div>
```

### CSS

```css
#input {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#content {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

### JS

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");
const observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    console.warn(entry);
  }
});

observer.observe(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, we still cannot monitor scrollHeight changes directly.

But there is a solution:

- Use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe#parameters) to detect `childList` changes. Set to `true` to monitor the target node for the addition of new child nodes or removal of existing child nodes.
- Use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to detects size changes of child nodes.

[scrollview-resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollview-resize):

```
export interface SVResizeObserverEntrie {
  /**
   * A reference to the `Element` being observed.
   */
  target: Element;

  /**
   * Current `scrollWidth` of the element.
   */
  scrollWidth: number;

  /**
   * Current `scrollHeight` of the element.
   */
  scrollHeight: number;

  /**
   * Previous `scrollWidth` of the element.
   */
  previousScrollWidth: number;

  /**
   * Previous `scrollHeight` of the element.
   */
  previousScrollHeight: number;
}

export interface SVObserveOptions {
  /**
   * Specifies the direction in which to listen for changes.
   */
  direction?: 'x' | 'y';
}

/**
 * The function called whenever an observed resize occurs.
 *
 * @param  entries - An array of `SVResizeObserverEntrie` objects that can be used to access the new dimensions of the element after each change.
 * @param  observer - A reference to the `SVResizeObserver` itself.
 */
export type SVResizeCallback = (entries: Readonly<SVResizeObserverEntrie>[], observer: SVResizeObserver) => void;

export class SVResizeObserver {
  private dataset: {
    target: Element;
    entrie: SVResizeObserverEntrie;
    direction?: 'x' | 'y';
    resize: ResizeObserver;
    mutation: MutationObserver;
  }[] = [];

  constructor(private callback: SVResizeCallback) {}

  /**
   * Observing the specified `Element`.
   *
   * @param target - A reference to an `Element` to be observed.
   */
  observe(target: Element, options?: SVObserveOptions) {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      this._checkChange();
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < target.children.length; i++) {
      resizeObserver.observe(target.children[i]);
    }

    const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(() => {
      this._checkChange();

      this.unobserve(target);
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      this.observe.apply(this, arguments as any);
    });
    mutationObserver.observe(target, { childList: true });

    const [scrollWidth, scrollHeight] = [target.scrollWidth, target.scrollHeight];
    this.dataset.push({
      target,
      entrie: {
        target,
        scrollWidth,
        scrollHeight,
        previousScrollWidth: scrollWidth,
        previousScrollHeight: scrollHeight,
      },
      direction: options?.direction,
      resize: resizeObserver,
      mutation: mutationObserver,
    });
  }

  /**
   * Ends the observing of a specified `Element`.
   *
   * @param target - A reference to an `Element` to be unobserved.
   */
  unobserve(target: Element) {
    const dataset = [];
    for (const data of this.dataset) {
      if (data.target === target) {
        data.resize.disconnect();
        data.mutation.disconnect();
      } else {
        dataset.push(data);
      }
    }

    this.dataset = dataset;
  }

  /**
   * Unobserves all observed `Element` targets.
   */
  disconnect() {
    for (const data of this.dataset) {
      data.resize.disconnect();
      data.mutation.disconnect();
    }

    this.dataset = [];
  }

  private _checkChange() {
    let hasChange = false;
    const entries: Readonly<SVResizeObserverEntrie>[] = [];
    for (const data of this.dataset) {
      const [scrollWidth, scrollHeight] = [data.target.scrollWidth, data.target.scrollHeight];

      const scrollWidthChange = data.entrie.scrollWidth !== scrollWidth;
      const scrollHeightChange = data.entrie.scrollHeight !== scrollHeight;
      switch (data.direction) {
        case undefined:
          hasChange = scrollWidthChange || scrollHeightChange;
          break;

        case 'x':
          hasChange = scrollWidthChange;
          break;

        case 'y':
          hasChange = scrollHeightChange;
          break;

        default:
          break;
      }

      data.entrie.previousScrollHeight = data.entrie.scrollHeight;
      data.entrie.previousScrollWidth = data.entrie.scrollWidth;
      data.entrie.scrollWidth = scrollWidth;
      data.entrie.scrollHeight = scrollHeight;
      entries.push(Object.freeze({ ...data.entrie }));
    }

    if (hasChange) {
      this.callback(entries, this);
    }
  }
}
```